# AngularJS ng-repeat filter works when hardcoded but not when passed as controller variable

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

So I want to make a drop down menu that changes the filter value of the ng-repeat like this:

```
  <div ng-repeat="{{filter}}">
```

so I have this line in the controller that right now is hard-coded

```
  $scope.filter = 'lang in langs | filter:{type:\'Interpreted\'}';
```

And I can verify that {{filter}} does spit out the string, but ng-repeat doesn't work when given that string as a double bracket variable, only when it's hard-coded in. Can you not pass angular controller variables to other angular functions like ng-repeat?

Comment: `ng-repeat="filter"` doesn't that work?

Comment: ng-repeat already parses the variable, so there is no need of curly braces `{{ }}`, you'd use curly braces in a non-ng attribute like `class="{{ cond ? 'black' : 'white' }}"`

Comment: Why not put the expression directly in the [`ngRepeat`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) directive. This is much more readable. Remember: AngularJS lets you extend HTML vocabulary for your application. The resulting environment is extraordinarily expressive, readable, and quick to develop. Currently, it's hard to see what your [`ngRepeat`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) directive is doing without looking inside the controller. At least be more semantic with the variable name.

Comment: @Ananth You're right about the brackets, but no that doesn't work.

Comment: @cnorthfield Because it will be assigned to a variable determined by a function in the controller, so the end result will be a drop down menu to change the filter

Comment: @AnthonyG Look at my updated answer regarding changing the filter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not simply inject the [`$filter`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) service into your controller and do the filtering there. You can simply filter your langs in your controller like so:

```
$scope.filteredLangs = $filter('filter')($scope.langs, {type:'Interpreted'});
```

Then you can repeat your filtered langs via the [`ngRepeat`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) directive:

```
<div ng-repeat="lang in filteredLangs">
```

**Remember, the [`ngRepeat`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) directive evaluates an expression so you do not need the curly braces as you have in your example.**

If you are simply looking to change the type in the filter then simply update a variable in the controller:

```
$scope.myType = "Interpreted";
```

In the view:

```
<div ng-repeat="lang in langs | filter: {type: myType}">
```